# Choice of pronoun to refer to 'one of us' when 'us' is male + female: they, he, she?

Tags: gender-neutral, question-tags, pronominal-agreement, grammatical-gender

Imagine yourself – a man – sitting next to someone you want to talk to – a woman – on a bus, train, plane, etc. After a while you say: 'One of us has to start talking / break the ice, don't they? / doesn't he? / doesn't she?'

Comment: Shouldn't it be *we*? It would still be plural I suppose.

Comment: "*One of us* always comes with subject *we*" -- http://www.learnenglishrapidly.com/2013/04/question-tags-verbs.html

Comment: Rule 2. (b) When the subject of the Statement is *all of us/ some of us/ none of us/ one of us/ most of us*, the subject of the question-tag would be 'we.'  http://books.google.co.in/books?id=mzDW9G-3jzgC&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=%22one+of+us%22+with+question-tag&source=bl&ots=fZsLycJ_XT&sig=SruKP6b4EeKlzl9k61U5sn87XLI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gC-hU6WrJdaLuATrgoKYCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22one%20of%20us%22%20with%20question-tag&f=false

Comment: In the situation pictured in the question, only one person can start talking, so 'we' does not seem logical here. This is what triggered my question.

Comment: @Kris - so you claim that _One of us is wrong_ is an incorrect sentence because _one of us_ is plural?

Comment: True. However, it **is** plural in the question-tag. The logic probably being that who among "us" is either not known or not relevant, so that only the "we" matters.

Comment: @oerkelens "One of us is wrong" has no question tag.

Comment: @oerkelens We are dealing with the question-tag here.

Comment: @Kris - So you would would really write _One of us is wrong, aren't we?_. I guess by analogy you would not bat an eyelid at _One of these balls is blue, aren't they?_

Comment: @oerkelens yes, "Then one of us is wrong, aren't we?" is exactly how it would be written. Same for the balls.

Comment: Time for my very first question :)

Comment: I'd rephrase it entirely, as something like, "One of us has to start talking, don't you think?"

Comment: @MartinMcCallion: an easy (and satisfactory, I must admit) way out. Strange: 'One of us must be wrong, mustn't you?'; less strange 'We've got to admit that one of us is wrong, haven't we?'

Comment: @MartinMcCallion: what I found special about the situation in the question was that by saying 'One of us has to start talking', the person speaking performs the action, so that the question of who will start speaking is no longer open and cannot be reflected in a question tag with a plural pronoun or a 'she', because the male spoke first.

Comment: This is hypothetical, right? Just a setup for the grammatical question? If not, I think you're going about it the wrong way. Bring a puppy. Chicks dig puppies.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion: why not turn your comment into an answer? which would then be my 'accepted answer', because I do not find any of the other answers satisfactory.

Comment: I agree with @MartinMcCallion. The obvious (to me) answer is "One of us has to start talking, don't I?"

Answer (score 3):

I'd rephrase it entirely, as something like, "One of us has to start talking, don't you think?"

Answer (score 2):

Use *we*.

> One of us has to start talking, don't we?

It seems a little strange, but that's because people wouldn't phrase the (rhetorical) question that way.

> One of us has to start talking.

or

> Shouldn't one of us start talking?

Comment: No, the reason it seems (more than) a little strange is because of the complete confusion of grammatical number. One of us _has_, so the subject is singular, but it becomes magically (?) plural in the question tag. [I would really appreciate a better explanation of that phenomenon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178565/one-of-us-is-wrong-arent-we). Well apart from the use of a different verb in the question tag - I would expect at least _haven't we_. But ok, that is all too common I guess :)

Comment: Please remember that gramar is not a set of rules that everyone has to follow. They are a set of approximate theories on how a language works, often confounded by people who actually use the language. You observe a pattern for grammatical number and then think it has to be true for everything. "One of us" therefore (assuming both men) *he*? No that seems really wrong. *We* seems right because that's what is used.

Comment: That is used? Not by me or anybody _I_ have ever spoken to. I am genuinely surprised there_are_ people that use it like that. Accordance of number is not just a vague idea, it is a pretty strong grammatical pattern in many languages, and it usually is simple ungrammatical to break it. _If_ there is any (prescriptive, no less!) exception for question tags or _one of X_, then I would be very pleased with a source. (And please, a source that is at least written in proper English - or is random elision of articles as in Kris' source also a new rule?)

Comment: I think the problem is the "one of us... don't X" doesn't come up often enough that we'd be reliably able to be sure which is right. The *don't we* version has one hit in Google books, whereas *don't they* has none. So statistically there is little difference that I can find. I am willing to admit that the balls example sounds fine with either *they* or *it*.

Comment: Maybe have a look at (the comments) to my question, I am not the only one surprised at this unexpected exception to a pretty straightforward grammar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Singular *they* is the modern, gender neutral term used increasingly in situations of mixed-gender crowds.

It's even more appropriate in the case where the mixed-'crowd' contains only two people. Using *he* would seem to put the onus of talking on the man, and using *she* would do the same for the women. So using the gender neutral singular *they* works best.

For more info on the use of singular they, see [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). It seems to be acceptable in most places, except *some* American audiences where it will 'make people doubt your literacy', but in my experience this seems to be vanishingly applicable in the modern sense.

ETA (because I jumped the gun and didn't think the whole thing through, before answering the call for gender-neutral singular) **in the particular case mentioned by the OP, the pronoun should indeed by *we***, as pointed out by a whole lot of people in the comment threads as well as by Matt in the answer below.

Comment: What's special about the situation in the question is that the action 'start talking', 'break the ice', if you prefer, can only be done by one person, and that person is a different gender from the other person: that's what makes the question  interesting in my view.

Comment: @user58319: that is why this answer is correct. _They_, even though it behaves like a plural, can (and often does!) indicate a _singular_ person of non-defined sex.

Comment: A real singular they would be "One of us has to start talking, doesn't they?" which I don't believe *anybody* would say.

Comment: @TimLymington What's your point, could you elaborate? The fact that it's used in a non-standard doesn't say anything about the existence of this usage. English is full of exceptions to the rules.

Comment: I've been using the singular *they* all my life, and to me it sounds ***really, really wrong*** here. The singular *they* should only be used in the third person. The only question tag that sounds at all reasonable to me here (although I wouldn't use it myself) is the singular *we*.

Comment: @PeterShor Yup, and I clearly mention that in my answer that while 'they' is a gender-neutral singular, the word to be used in the OP's situation is, in fact, 'we'. So I'm not sure of the point of this comment?

Comment: Yes, but somebody reading your answer might get the idea that "they" is only slightly incorrect here. I wanted to correct that possible misapprehension.

Comment: @PeterShor OK, noted. Have highlighted the relevant part to be more visible. **

Answer (score -2):

An English language imperfection. An imperfection of the language of Shakespeare. The rule of the tag questions having to contain the pronoun of the person the question refers to, that very neat grammatical construction fails misarably in this case.