# ...if one of us dropped "our phone" or "his phone"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, personal-pronouns, pronominal-agreement, grammatical-person

> It would be ruinous if one of us dropped our phone in the river, so each of us put their phone in their bag and set them aside.

In the sentence above, is it incorrect to say "if **one** of us dropped **his** phone in the river" and "put their phone**s** in their bag**s**"?

Comment: Related: [One of us is wrong, aren't we?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178565/one-of-us-is-wrong-arent-we), https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178529/choice-of-pronoun-to-refer-to-one-of-us-when-us-is-male-female-they-he?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This is a situation where 'singular their' sounds awful. I'd be tempted to use _his_   gender-neutrally throughout. Or _her_ if both actors are female.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "source novel"? If the source of the sentence is a novel, please give the actual title of the book and the name of the author.

Comment: @Edwin: I think 'singular their' may sound awful because it's immediately preceded by 'singular our'.

Comment: @Peter I don't even like 'It would be ruinous if one of us dropped their phone in the river ...'.

Comment: @Edwin: which is why some people use singular *our* there.

Answer (score 1):

The subject *"each of us"* is singular, so if you use singular *his* the first time, you need to keep on using it:

> It would be ruinous if one of us dropped *his* phone in the river, so each of us put *his* phone in *his* bag and set *it* aside.

And even if you use singular *they*, it should be:

> ... so each of us put *their* phone in *their* bag and set *it* aside.

or

> ... so each of us put *their* phone in *their* bag and *we* set *them* aside.

(So the original quote is wrong ... it appears that the author got singular and plural *they* confused.)